# Creating an installation package for a Visual Studio 2008 C# application and another installation for Mschart ALL-IN-ONE... Is this possible?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, mschart, advanced-installer

I have *Inno Setup* installed and also *Advanced Installer 10.9 (Professional edition)*, and was wondering if I can create a multi-installation setup package that has both my application and *Mschart*? I have tried to simply create a single package that contains the _Mschart_file, but when another computer (user) doesn't have it installed already (*Mschart*), it won't allow you to view the graphs. I've read about Merging Modules in the [*Advanced Installer 10.9*](http://www.advancedinstaller.com), this program is also really slick and PRETTY! So would prefer to use this.

So, when the user opens up setup, It will install the application first then *Mschart* (vice versa) sequentially.

Comment: you cand have prerequisites in Advanced Installer too, just the same as in VS. Press F1 in Prerequisites page for more info, when your project is loaded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Visual Studio you can create a boostrap package with your prerequisites and add it to tour msi package. The installer will detect where your prerequisite is installed or no and take the appropriate decision.

See this article for more info:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165429.aspx